# Grouping by two columns and add a third column based on a condition of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following input:

```
Date        Type      Cond 
01-05-2001  A         NULL
01-05-2001  B         NULL
01-05-2001  C         x     
01-05-2001  A         y   
            .            
            .
            .
01-08-2001  B         NULL
01-08-2001  B         NULL
01-08-2001  C         NULL
01-08-2001  A         NULL
```

I want a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date         Cond      Count
0            TRUE      2
               .
               .
               .
92           FALSE     1
```

Basically I want to group by exact dates and the type (here its A) but replace the dates by a number and the type but the number of types at a date. Than I want to mark the entries as TRUE if the Cond 
column has at least one value that is not NULL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use `factorize` to enumerate the dates, `eq` to check for `A`:

```
(df.Type.eq('A')
   .groupby(df.Date.factorize()[0])
   .value_counts()
   .unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
   .rename_axis(['Date','Cond'])          
   .reset_index(name='Count')
)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this! Is `eq` the equivalent of `df[Type == 'A']`?

Comment: I get an `unexpected token ")"` error at the closing bracket of the groupby method.
Edit: Apparently it has to be `.groupby([df.Date.factorize()[0]])` the closing `]` was missing

Comment: @Blubsiwubsi `df['Type'].eq('A')` is equivalent to `df['Type'] == 'A'`. And thanks for pointing out the mistake. The code is updated.

Comment: I see. I also had to change `.rename_axis(columns=['Date','Cond'])` to `.rename_axis(['Date','Cond'])`

Comment: Ah, yes. Shoulda been `index` instead of `columns`. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you too :).
It's nearly perfect the only thing missing is that their should just be either TRUE or FALSE for one date. What I mean by that is that the counts should be added and if at least one row is TRUE then the resulting one should also be true. Sorry if the example did not make that clear.

Comment: Its still like this:  

`Date    Cond     Count: 0          True      554; 0 False 904`

but it should be:

`Date    Cond     Count: 0          True      1458`